# Test AngularFireAuth Wrapper, without using AngularFireAuth mock

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, authentication

I would like to have a AuthWrapper Service that wraps the AngularFireAuth Service. Something like this.

```
// EDIT: Adding some import statements.
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthWrapperService } from './auth-wrapper.service';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {AngularFireAuth, AngularFireAuthModule} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthWrapper {
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this.afAuth.user;
  }

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): Promise<String> {
    let authPromise: Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential> =
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    return authPromise
      .then((value) => {
        return value.user.email;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        return error.message;
      });
  }
}
```

I want a wrapper, so that I can test my connection to AngularFireAuth. Other tests mock the AuthWrapper.

( Reason for not mocking AngularFireAuth: Say I mock AngularFireAuth, then I am determining the mock's return values. Then I am saying that I understand what these values would look like. It is not safe to assume this without ever testing these by calling the backend. Say google changes how the results of the real AngularFireAuth's methods, I would then be forced to change the results of each of my AngularFireAuth mocks. Instead it is better to wrap AngularFireAuth in a wrapper, and just change that wrapper's methods to conform to google's changes. )

My tests in Karmine and Jasmine result in an "Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms error." I know the user is signed it because the first expect passes, but how do I get the second expect to work?:

```
describe('AuthWrapperService', () => {
  let fireAuthService: AngularFireAuth;
  let password = "dcbA4321!";

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFireModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule
      ],
      providers: [AngularFireAuth, AuthWrapperService],
      declarations: []
    })
    fireAuthService = TestBed.get(AngularFireAuth);
  });

  it('should sign in user', async() => {
    const email = "anyemail@gmail.com";
    let authWrap = new AuthWrapperService(fireAuthService);
    let userEmail = await authWrap.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    expect(userEmail).toBe("anyemail@gmail.com");
    let obs = authWrap.isAuthenticated();
    let promise = obs.toPromise();
    let user = await promise.then((result) => {return result});
    expect(user.email).toBe("anyemail@gmail.com");
  });
});
```

I haven't seen any Angular testing code, where the AngularFireAuth isn't mocked.

Comment: Ideally unit testing is about testing an entity in isolation, so we should mock the dependent service. Don't you want to mock AngularFireAuth ? Even if you are testing AngularFireAuth, you need to return the mock values from the promises.

Comment: I'm not testing AngularFireAuth. I'm testing its wrapper, AuthWrapperService. I understand there are diff ways of thinking about testing, but I believe I don't mock what I don't own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the tests that worked for me with a time interval of 5000ms. I did test them with "bad@gmail.com" in the expect lines to make sure the expect lines were actually running, and yes, the expect lines are actually passing. I intend to only run the AuthWrapperService tests periodically since they hit the database. I will mock the AuthWrapperService in other tests. Before I run these tests I delete the existing users in the firebase database manually through the firebase console. I do run both of these tests in one go, (inside one describe block).

```
it('should create new user', async() => {
  const annEmail = "ann@gmail.com";
  let authWrap = new AuthWrapperService(fireAuthService);
  await authWrap.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(annEmail, password).then(
    ((testEmail) => {
      expect(fireAuthService.auth.currentUser.email).toBe(annEmail);
    })
  )
  await fireAuthService.auth.signOut();
});

it('should return error message when user already exists', async() => {
  const email = 'ben@gmail.com';
  const error = 'already in use';
  let authWrap = new AuthWrapperService(fireAuthService);
  await authWrap.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((value: String) => {
      expect(fireAuthService.auth.currentUser.email).toBe(email);
    });
  await fireAuthService.auth.signOut();
  expect(fireAuthService.auth.currentUser).toBeNull();
  await authWrap.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((value: String) => {
      expect(value).toContain('already in use');
    });
  await fireAuthService.auth.signOut();
});
```

I decided to use fireAuthService.auth.currentUser.email instead of the AuthWrapperService's isAuthenticated() method to directly test that my AuthWrapperService's createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method creates a user in firebase.

I realize that this is not a unit test, but I have decided that it is better to have an integration test than to mock methods that I don't own.

The following test also worked for me within 5000ms and uses the isAuthenticated() method.

```
it('should create user cat', async() => {
  const catEmail = "cat@gmail.com";
  let authWrap = new AuthWrapperService(fireAuthService);
  let userEmail = await authWrap.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(catEmail, password);
  expect(userEmail).toBe(catEmail);
  await authWrap.isAuthenticated().subscribe({
    next(user) {
      expect(user.email).toBe(catEmail);
    }
  });
  console.log("cat, timeinterval: " + jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL);
  await fireAuthService.auth.signOut();
});
```

The following "dan test" resulted in time outs. I tried 29000ms once and it ran out of time. Most runs of this test were 10 seconds. Many times, but not always, this test passes correctly if the user is already a user before the test is run (so it's not really creating a user during the test). One time this test passed correctly when the user had not been created before the test, but I ran this many times without the user existing before the test and it failed. I'm not sure why that would be.

```
it('should create user dan', done => {
  const datEmail = "dan@gmail.com";
  let authWrap = new AuthWrapperService(fireAuthService);
  authWrap.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
    {
      next(user){
        expect(user.email).toBe(datEmail);
        done();
      }
    }
  );
  authWrap.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(datEmail, password);
  console.log("dan, timeinterval: " + jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL);
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide me documentation which you are using for Angular Fire Auth? I am not able to find this.afAuth.user but i found authState or currentUser which return same value  Observable<firebase.User>. It returns only the value of signed in user or null. Can you please add  error block as well. As i told you that we cannot control it completely whether we will get the data in time or not.

Comment: AngulaFireAuth: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly whats not working now, it ran out of time when you call isAuthenticated method without creating a user. Right?? Is there any other scenario as well?

Comment: The test using async does work. I am only providing the 'dan test' to be helpful to future users. Future users may have the same problem when trying to get done() to work. I can confirm done() in this manner does not work.

Comment: Since you asked, this is the result of the dan test: 'dan, timeinterval: 29000'

 Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 29000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
     at <Jasmine>

Comment: Can you run your tests again using this for your isAthenticated method ->   isAuthenticated(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this.afAuth.currentUser;
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209584/discussion-between-prince-and-flobacca).

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, its not a good practice to not mock dependencies in case of unit testing. Any cohesive unit should be tested in isolation. And let say if our dependency has number of other dependencies then we cannot provide them all.

When you test the code with the actual dependency, you are not doing unit testing; you are doing integration testing.

Please see this for difference between Integration testing and Unit testing - https://angular.io/guide/testing#use-e2e-end-to-end-to-test-more-than-a-single-unit

You are facing this error because your async spec finishes after the default time out that jasmine has specified, which is 5 seconds. Please find the jasmine documentation on this. **URL** - https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-42

You need to manipulate the jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL as per your need, assign it some large value as shown in below example:

```
describe("long asynchronous specs", function() {
    var originalTimeout;
    beforeEach(function() {
      originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 60000; // 60 second (use value as per need)
    });

    it("takes a long time", function(done) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        done();
      }, 9000);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });
  });
```

It still depend on the network as well how fast your promise returns the value. I would suggest you to change the value for jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL only in test where you are working with actual dependecies.

I hope this will help.